# iPad app for organizing, rating, and noting photos

Tags: ipad, photos.app

I've imported a bunch of my photos from Lightroom (not directly of course) to use my iPad as a scrap book. So that I can look at them, and decide whether they belong in a series or should be included in my portofio.

Currently I'm doing this by e-mailing myself each photo with some notes and thoughts.

Is there an app where I can view my photos, and put notes against them. And ideally also organize them into groups where I feel they work together?

thanks

### Update

I should have noted this before. It needs to be an offline solution. Although I e-mail myself, I compose the e-mails offline as it's not so important when the notes get to me, but rather that I am writing them whenever i want, while looking through the photos.

cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few apps around, although I have yet to find the perfect fit.

Sortshots, http://www.sortshots.com/, is one option. You load the photos from Lightroom onto the iPad with the Itunes file sharing feature, and you can then edit metadata on the ipad offline. The results can be sent back to Lightroom by copying the photos out of the iTunes file sharing feature.

The drawback of this workflow is mainly three things:
1) Cumbersome to manually drag and drop photos between iTunes to sync
2) Not good workflow to get metadata back to e.g. Lightroom, as you need to overwrite the old photos with the new edited ones from iPad (if I understood it correctly)
3) If you want the photos to appear in the photos.app, you need to have the same photos twice on the iPad, eating double disk space.

Comment: thanks ripperdoc. I guess we're still missing a really good app for this. but thanks anyways!

Comment: @RipperDoc – Thanks for recommending Sortshots here. Regarding the drawbacks you mentioned:

Comment: 1) Apart from itunes document share, SortSshots also provides an inbuilt FTP Server and you can transfer files wirelessly to SortShots by using any standard FTP client like Filezila. So in other words, start FTP server on Sortshots, start FTP client on your PC/Mac, connect to Sortshots and transfer files as you do with regular FTP.

Comment: 2) For getting metadata back to Lightroom, you don’t need to overwrite your original images. You can copy it to any other location on your PC/Mac by FTP or may be iTunes document sharing itself

Comment: 3) The third point regarding photo app.. well that is something which is beyond control as it is due to limitations imposed by Big Apple on third party developers and apps.

Comment: Hope this helps. Please feel free to write us should you have any questions Thanks,
Sortshots Team

Answer (score 2):

You can create yourself a Flickr account and upload your pictures to Flickr (as you are already sending the pictures via mail, it should not be an issue).

On Flickr, you will be able to put your pictures as favorite or not, put description, comments, keywords.
You can arrange them in Sets and Collections and also keep them private so no-one can see them, unless you decide otherwise.

You have app for this on iPad/iPhone, as well as the website on the Mac or the numerous exiting applications on Mac interfacing with Flickr (Lightroom is also one of them).

The drawback is the [limits](http://www.flickr.com/help/limits/) existing in the free version, but depending on your usage, it could be OK for you.

Comment: +1 hey thanks ludo. I need an offline solution. I know I send e-mails, but I compose them offline, and it means I can view my photos without needing to connect... thanks though

Answer (score 1):

As per my experience Sortshots is an excellent app!!Very easy to use and works perfect for me.

Comment: +1 thanks, I'll check it out. Does it let you edit the metadata too?

Answer (score 1):

A new app called [Photosmith](http://blog.photosmithapp.com/index.php/photosmith-the-grand-tour/) might fit the bill - it allows tagging and organising on the iPad and has a Lightroom plugin on the computer that syncs with your iPad.