# photo apps for ipad over wifi

Tags: ios, photos, folders, accessibility

I have a lot of family photos and home video stored on network folders (my PC, my NAS) accessible via wi-fi.

Are there photo manager and photo editor apps for me to directly work my pictures on my IPad?

By directly, I mean edit the picture (e.g fix red eyes, contrast) in the photo editor app without having to open a file browser app, copy it to my ipad and copy it back on my network folder. It also mean I can view and delete picture in the folder directly within the photo manager app.

P.S. I am open to jailbreaking my ipad or other solutions such as mounting the folders so they appear as local folder as long as the apps can open these files as it does for the Camera roll.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10931/ipad-app-for-organizing-rating-and-noting-photos

Answer (score 1):

If your nas supports DLNA then that opens out great possibility's. Just write DNLA photo any you will find plenty of Apps otherwise you will be stuck with NAS unfortunately i dont have any recommendation for nas connection.

This is what i recommend..

https://itunes.apple.com/bh/app/smartstor-fusion-stream-dlna/id410280827?mt=8

https://itunes.apple.com/bh/app/imediashare-lite-video-on-tv/id302026401?mt=8

Answer (score 1):

Photography is my passion and I use a variety of PC based tools and mobile apps . On iPhone and iPads ,  I mostly edit my photographs on using an app called “[Photo Splash FX](https://itunes.apple.com/es/app/photo-splash-fx-editor-multiple/id482487175?mt=8)”. Its easy to use interface, plethora of editing options and stability made it my favorite app.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your issue is a compounded one, in that you want a photo manager that has an editing solution that works between your iPad and your PC (assume Windows).

The easiest solution that I can think of is to seriously consider switching to a Mac instead of a PC, because what you are looking for is solved with an App called iPhoto. It comes with every new Mac and can be purchased on the App Store for iOS devices for $4.99.

iPhoto manages your photo library by doing all of the cataloguing and archiving for you within a very intuitive user interface. You can sync your photos between your Mac and iOS devices by direct connection or through iCloud. It also comes with some very decent editing tools like removing red-eye, cropping, basic filters, brightness/contrast, exposure, and more.

If you want something more robust than iPhoto, then you can move up to Aperture on your Mac, which conveniently also uses your iPhoto library.

That said, if you insist on working with the PC, you may want to look at iPhoto for your iPad, and syncing your iPhoto library on your iPad through iTunes on your PC, but you will still have to do a lot of manual file management with your photo folders. It's just not as "elegant" a solution, but it can work with some effort.